# mysql count records added per day

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mysql. I was wondering how to output how many records were added to a table per day.

This data

```
loggedID              datelogged
   1                  2015-10-03
   2                  2015-10-03
   3                  2015-10-05
   4                  2015-10-05
   5                  2015-10-06
   6                  2015-10-06
   7                  2015-10-06
```

would output

```
2015-10-03  2
2015-10-04  0
2015-10-05  2
2015-10-06  3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Time to go read a SQL tutorial. This is **very** basic stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT datelogged, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY datelogged
```

Comment: The answer was the close, but it did not have "2015-10-04  0" in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do it in SQL alone, so I did it using a bit of PHP. The output will go to a graph. Thats why I need the dates with no logged calls to show as 0.

```
<?php

    # Open the database
    require 'config.php';     
    require 'database_connect.php';

        function datediff($date1) {
                $date2 = "2015-09-14";
                $date1 = date_create($date1);
                $date2 = date_create($date2);
                $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
                $realdiff = $diff->format("%a");
                return $realdiff;
        }

    $query = "select datelogged, count(*) as daycalls from rti_loggedcalls group by datelogged";

    try
    {
        $sth = $db->query($query);
        while ($row = $sth->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        $date = ($row["datelogged"]);
        $mdate = datediff($date);
        $output[$mdate] = ($row["daycalls"]);
        } 
    }

    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        printf("We had a problem: %s\n", $e->getMessage());
    }


    for ($i = 0; $i < ($mdate + 1) ; $i++) {
        echo $i." ".(0 + $output[$i])."<br>";
    }
?>
```